# Google Maps "setOnLocationEnabled" crashes on Android 2.3.7 -- Since change to Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project in Android Studio that displays a map.
Everything works fine (map included) until I try to call `mMap_.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`. It produces the following error:

```
09-29 00:55:41.873    1450-1450/com.packages.appname W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40218560)
09-29 00:55:41.914    1450-1450/com.packages.appname E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packages.appname/activity.SelectLocationInMapActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f100000
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f100000
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:929)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:736)
    at maps.ag.bp.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.ag.an.c(Unknown Source)
    at bns.onTransact(SourceFile:274)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at activity.SelectLocationInMapActivity.onCreate(SelectLocationInMapActivity.java:85)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
    ... 11 more
```

Resource not found... is weird. The very same code WORKS IN ANDROID 4 right now. It also works smoothly in 2.x if I remove the conflicting call. So, it is not a problem of API key, how library is included, SDK or editor not up-to-date...

The problem appeared after I migrated my "old" android studio project to the Gradle system. Before switching, I was using the .jar file located at `<android sdk>\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs`, but now it is automatically downloaded/imported from the spec in build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'
    ...
}
```

Is anyone having the same issue? Do you have any suggestions? I have no ideas left...